Why are my SAV variable names not being exported from SAS Studio correctly?
I am using SAS Studio. I am exporting a df with 57 Observations and 1151 variables. I am using proc export with DBMS = SAV to convert the file into a SAV and move it to my library Folder. I am able to download the file to my machine and open it in SPSS, although only a small portion of the variable names transfer to SPSS.
I ran this code:
proc export data=import  outfile='/home/u63943531/Imported Data'  dbms=sav;  run;
And got "Imported Data.sav" in my library. I then right clicked and selected "Download File." The file downloads correctly, although most of the variable names when opened in SPSS are auto generated. I want the variable names that were in the SAS df.
It is fine if it remains in my work folder.
Here is the code used to generate the dataset
%web_drop_table(WORK.IMPORT);
FILENAME REFFILE '/home/u63943531/Imported Data/CSV_Desktop_Version_2024-07-10-210526449754432448585360030.csv';
PROC IMPORT DATAFILE=REFFILE
    DBMS=CSV
    OUT=WORK.IMPORT;
    GETNAMES=YES;
RUN; 
PROC CONTENTS DATA=WORK.IMPORT; 
RUN;
%web_open_table(WORK.IMPORT);


What do the variable names look like?  Are they longer than 8 characters? Do they include characters other than digits and letters?

By df do you mean a SAS dataset?

I suspect that the names were already messed up in the SAS dataset.  Did you attempt to use PROC IMPORT to create the data from a text file?  Unless you have very short names over 1,000 variable names will not fit in the 32k limit that PROC IMPORT has for reading the header line of CSV file.

Hey Tom, sorry for the delay in response. My df I mean SAS dataset. I looked at the variables names in SAS and you are correct, the names got messed up when I uploaded them to SAS. Looking at the excel spreadsheet before they were uploaded, all the variable names are intact. Why are the variable names no being transferred to SAS studio correctly?

Show the CODE you ran to make the SAS dataset.  Did you write the code yourself? Or did you use some import wizard that wrote the code?   Using PROC IMPORT on an actual XSLX file would NOT mess up the variable names.  But using it on a CSV file with too long a header line will.

OK, the code has been updated to the original comment

Is this now a different question? Sounds like the problem is when you run PROC IMPORT to load data from a CSV into a SAS dataset, you don't like the variable names?  If so, I would suggest closing this question, and opening a new one.

I thought you had an EXCEL file?  That code is reading a TEXT file. Do not use PROC IMPORT to read a text file.  Write your own data step.  You will then have complete control over the variable names (and type and storage length etc).

@Quentin it is the same question, I am just now realizing the SAS variable names are not being uploaded correctly, when I originally thought it was not being uploaded to SPSS correctly. I figured out the problem is occurring early then I originally thought.

@tom It has always been an CSV file. I had opened it previously in EXCEL to check the variable names and observations to check and see if the variable names changed when uploaded to SAS studio. They are being changed.

Check this question that has basically your same problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014608/import-issue-with-sas-due-to-large-columns-headers

Your problem does not appear to be related to PROC EXPORT or to the creation of SPSS SAV files.
Instead you have not created the SAS dataset properly.  To read a text file into a SAS dataset is very simple. Just write a data step that defines and reads in the variables.  The data step can be very simple.
Use INFILE to point to the file skipping the header row, use DSD option to properly handle a delimited file and the TRUNCOVER option to handle any lines with empty last variable.
Use LENGTH (or perhaps ATTRIB with the LENGTH= option) to DEFINE the type and storage length of each variable.  Define them in the order they appear in the file and the later INPUT statement will be simpler.  If you want to use the header row to build the LENGTH statement then just copy and paste it into your program and remove the commas (and possible convert the header values into actual variable names) and insert the desired storage length.
Attach formats and/or informats to any variables that NEED them.  Most variables will NOT need them. The main exception are DATE, TIME or DATETIME values.
Use INPUT statement to read the variables.  And if you have defined the variables in the same order as they appear in the text file the INPUT statement can just use a simple positional variable list to specify the variables to be read.
Example:
 data want;
   infile reffile dsd firstobs=2 truncover ;
   length var1 8 var2 $20 ..... varlast 8 ;
   informat datevar date.;
   format datevar date9.;
   input var1 -- varlast ;
 run;

If you must use a guessing procedure to guess how to define the variables then  remember that PROC IMPORT can only "see" the first 32K bytes of the header row.
So if you have really long header row instead read the data skipping the header row
 proc import dbms=csv file=reffile out=import replace ;
    getname = NO ;
    datarow = 2;
   guessingrows = max ;
 run;

You can then read the header row separately.
 data headers;
   infile reffile dsd obs=1 lrecl=1000000 ;
   varnum+1;
   input label :$256. @@;
   name = substr(label,1,32);
 run;

Which you can then use to rename the variables if you want.
Or just use another guessing tool that does not have the 32K limit on the length of the header row.
Such as this macro:  https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/csv2ds.sas
filename reffile '/home/u63943531/Imported Data/CSV_Desktop_Version_2024-07-10-210526449754432448585360030.csv'
  lrecl=1000000;
%csv2ds(reffile,out=import,replace=1)

